# Regex for "password must contain at least one non-alphanumeric character"

Tags: javascript, regex

I am looking to use regex pattern to replace membership method `MembershipCreateStatus.InvalidPassword` for Password validation. Criteria for valid password is "A valid password must contain at least one non-alphanumeric character. (`test.123` is an example of a valid password)". I have used following regex pattern, but it does not seem to match criteria.

```
/^(?=.*(\W)).{5,20}$/
```

Comment: What is wrong with that regex? `\W` matches all chars other than `[A-Za-z0-9_]` - does it mean you need to allow `_` as a part of the lookahead restriction? Then replace `(?=.*(\W))` with `(?=.*[^a-zA-Z0-9])`

Comment: homework/assignment question?

Comment: No @RishiDua it isnt, thanks anyway!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
/([^a-zA-Z\d])+([a-zA-Z\d])+|([a-zA-Z\d])+([^a-zA-Z\d])+/
```